# Pulling data from JSON file using jQuery and splitting it into groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I am currently frying my brain to get one specific part of my website working.

It consists of clicking a button and checking it's "data-group" attribute. This should open up another div and populate it with content being pulled from a local JSON file, which I have to filter according to the data-group attribute of each one of the buttons.

My current JSON looks like this:

```
 [
{
    "group": "editing",
    "question": "How does Editing work?",
    "answer": "Editing Editing Editing Editing Editing Editing works just fine is pretty cool to see it working hey this is just placeholder text to check whether it is working or not."
},
{
    "group": "distribution",
    "question": "How does Distribution work?",
    "answer": "Distribution Distribution Distribution Distribution Distribution Distribution works just fine is pretty cool to see it working hey this is just placeholder text to check whether it is working or not."
},
{
    "group": "setup",
    "question": "How does Setup work?",
    "answer": "Setup Setup Setup Setup Setup Setup Setup works just fine is pretty cool to see it working hey this is just placeholder text to check whether it is working or not."
},
{
    "group": "profiles",
    "question": "How do Profiles work?",
    "answer": "Profiles Profiles Profiles Profiles Profiles Profiles Profiles Profiles works just fine is pretty cool to see it working hey this is just placeholder text to check whether it is working or not."
},
{
    "group": "payment",
    "question": "How does Payment work?",
    "answer": "Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment works just fine is pretty cool to see it working hey this is just placeholder text to check whether it is working or not."
}
{
    "group": "about",
    "question": "How does Payment work?",
    "answer": "Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment Payment works just fine is pretty cool to see it working hey this is just placeholder text to check whether it is working or not."
}
```

]

my Javascript looks like this:

```
$('.groupBtn').on('click', function(data){
    data.preventDefault();

    var $root = $('html, body');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.angle').offset().top
    }, 500);

    var attributeId = $(this).data('group');

    if ($(this).attr('group') == attributeId) {

    } else {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        $.getJSON("js/faq-content.json", function() {


        })
        .done(function(data){

            $.each(data.questions, function(i, question){
                console.log(question);
                $('.resultsList.open').append('<article class="result"><div class="question"><p>'+ question.question +'</p><div class="plus"></div></div>');
            });
        });
    }

    $('.resultsList').each(function(){

        $(this).hide();
        var selectedAttribute = $('.selected').data('group');

        if ($(this).data('group') == selectedAttribute) {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share some markup or a fiddle

Comment: You can simply do this `var groupQuestions = data.questions.filter(v => v.group == attributeId)` and then loop through the result to add the questions `$.each(groupQuestions, .....`.

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON("js/faq-content.json", function() {

```
    })
    .done(function(data){
      var groupQuestions = data.questions.filter(data => data.group == attributeId);
        $.each(groupQuestions, function(i, question){
            console.log(question);
            $('.resultsList.open').append('<article class="result"><div class="question"><p>'+ question.question +'</p><div class="plus"></div></div>');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("js/faq-content.json", function() {})
    .done(function(data){
      data.questions.forEach(question => {
          if(question.group === attributeId){
            $('.resultsList.open').append('<article class="result"><div class="question"><p>'+ question.question +'</p><div class="plus"></div></div>');
          }
      });
    });
```

Since the filter would be slower than forEach, its highly recommended to use foreach which filters the data and appends to resultslist